# search for exact string in unix

Tags: sed, awk, grep, xml

I have a file, *xyz.txt*, which has one string per line.
How do I search *xyz.txt* for an exact match?
I get an input string, eg. `defabc`, from another app.
If `defabc` is found, it should return *true*, else *false*. Can I use regex in `grep`?

Sample file: xyz.txt:

```
abc
def
abc_def
def_abc
abcdef
defabc
uvx
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `xml`? I see no `xml` here? (But if there was, the question would be a very different one...)

Answer (score 3):

With the `-F` option, `grep` looks for exact matches (regex features turned off):

```
$ grep -F "defabc" xyz.txt
defabc
```

`grep` sets an appropriate return code so that we can test for true or false:

```
$ if grep -qF "defabc" xyz.txt; then echo True; else echo False; fi
True
$ if grep -qF "Defabc" xyz.txt; then echo True; else echo False; fi
False
```

Because we only want `grep` to set a return code, the `-q` option is used to tell `grep` to be quiet (omit normal output).

#### Restricting the match to whole words

If we want to match `defabc` but not `defabc1`, we can add the `-w` option to restrict the match to whole words:

```
if grep -qFw "defabc" xyz.txt; then echo True; else echo False; fi
```

`man grep` explains how `grep` defines a "word":

> **-w, --word-regexp**
>  Select  only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must
>   either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word
>   constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the
>   line or followed by a non-word constituent character.
>   Word-constituent  characters  are  letters, digits, and the
>   underscore.

#### Capturing the output in a shell variable

To capture the output of a command, we use *command substitution* which takes the form `$(...)`:

```
$ r=$(if grep -qF "defabc" xyz.txt; then echo True; else echo False; fi)
$ echo $r
True
```

#### Capturing the exit code in a shell variable

```
grep -qF "defabc" xyz.txt
r=$?
```

`r` will be zero if there was a match, 1 if there wasn't, or 2 if some other error occurred.

Comment: Appreciate John for quick reply. Sorry I am new to unix. How can I assign the result to a variable?

Comment: Easily done but which result?  The matching string in the file?  The words True or False?  The return code?

Comment: true or false will do. Appreciate!
Can I do this:
result=`grep -F "$input" $myFile`
   
               if [ "$result" != $null ]; then
                   endResult=true
                 else
                 endResult=false
     
               fi

Comment: @kumar2008 It's simpler than that.  See the updated answer for how to use command substitution to capture the output.

Comment: Typically, the output of a command is considered `true` if it gives `0`; else it is considered `false`.  So, you could conceivably make the above simpler if you just say `r=$(grep -qF "defabc" xyz.txt)`.  You can check `r` and consider it `true` if it equals `0`; else `false`.

Comment: @unxnut Good idea.  One change is needed: to capture the exit code itself, one would need `r=$(grep -qF "defabc" xyz.txt; echo $?)`.   Without the `echo $?` statement, the shell variable `r` would be empty.  An advantage of your idea is that one can distinguish no match (exit code=1) from execution error (exit code=2).

Comment: If I give defabc in grep it also returns defabc1, defabc2.  I need only defabc. 

Thanks!

Comment: Replace `-qF` with `-qFw` and tell me if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @kumar2008 Excellent.  `-w` restricts the match to whole words.  I updated the answer with a section that shows its use.

Comment: anchors are another (maybe more grep-like?) method: `grep '^defabc$' xyz.txt`

Comment: @user1794469 Anchors are good: it depends on whether the OP wants whole lines or whole words.  By the way, `-w` is "grep-like" enough that it is included in both the GNU and [BSD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html) versions.

Answer (score 0):

Command to search the exact expression in Korn Shell of Unix

```
grep -w "SEARCH_EXPRESSION" FILE_TO_BE_SEARCHED
```

The above command searches for the exact word or search expression.